# Ackermann Table Geneation

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array, ackermann

I'm working on learning more about Ackermann's function, recursion time, and functionology in general, however, my code won't compile. I have a feeling it's something to do with the arrays in `acktgen()`, but I'm not 100% certain.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int ack(int m, int n){
    if(m==0) return n+1;
    else if (n==0) return ack(m,1);
    else return ack(m-1,ack(m,n-1));
}

int acktgen(const int s, const int t){
    int acktable[s+1][t+1];
    for (int i = 1 ; i= t+1; ++i){ //column labels
        acktable[0][i]= i-1 ;
    }
    for (int i = 1 ; i= s+1; ++i){  //row labels
        acktable[i][0]= i-1 ;
    } 
    for (int i = 1; i<=s+1; ++i){
        for (int j = 1; j<=t+1; ++j){
            acktable[i][j]= ack(i-1,j-1);
        }
    }
    return(acktable);
}

int main(){
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++) {
            cout<<acktgen(4,4)[i][j]<< "\t";
        }
    }
}
```

I know this isn't the most efficient Ackermann algorithm, but I'm just using it as an example.

Compiler Error:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int acktgen(int, int)':
prog.cpp:26:17: error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)[(t + 1)]' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
  return(acktable);
                 ^
prog.cpp:14:6: warning: address of local variable 'acktable' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
  int acktable[s+1][t+1];
      ^
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:32:24: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
    cout<<acktgen(4,4)[i][j]<< "\t";
                        ^
```

Comment: Please post the compiler error.

Comment: And done. I knew I had forgotten to do _something_.

Comment: BTW, what compiler are you using?  The errors I get are these:  http://ideone.com/sZ4OMF  Those errors are the ones I would have expected.

Comment: I'm using IDEONE C++14. http://ideone.com/4CglyM

Comment: Those compiler errors are not for the code posted.

Comment: Yeah, they must have been from a previous execution, let me redo.

Comment: Error logs and code fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through each error and warning:

```
> prog.cpp: In function 'int acktgen(int, int)': prog.cpp:26:17: error:
> invalid conversion from 'int (*)[(t + 1)]' to 'int' [-fpermissive]  
> return(acktable);
```

You declared your `acktgen` function to return an int, but instead you're returning an address.  I don't know what your intention is here, but if it is to return a single value from the array, then you return that value, i.e.

`return acktgen[0][4];`

or something like that.

---

```
> prog.cpp:14:6: warning: address of local variable 'acktable' returned
> [-Wreturn-local-addr]   int acktable[s+1][t+1];
```

You are returning the address of a local variable.  Doing so is undefined behavior in C++, so don't do it.  When the function returns, all local variables go away.  Therefore attempting to return (and use) the address of something that isn't there isn't going to work (or it may work, but only by chance).

---

```
> prog.cpp: In function 'int main()': prog.cpp:32:24: error: invalid
> types 'int[int]' for array subscript
>     cout<<acktgen(4,4)[i][j]<< "\t";
```

This is not correct, due to `acktgen` returning an int, not an array or array-like object.

Basically you need to give us more information on what you expected to return in the `acktgen` function.  Was it really supposed to be an array?  Was it supposed to be just a single value?

---

Some things with your code:

1) Declaring arrays with non constant expressions is not legal in ANSI
    C++:

```
int acktable[s+1][t+1];
```

That line of code is not legal C++.  To simulate an array, you can use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> acktable(s+1, std::vector<int>(t+1));
```

2) Your loop condition is written incorrectly:

```
   for (int i = 1 ; i = t+1; ++i){ //column labels
```

Look at the middle condition -- is that what you want, that the loop only continues if `i == t+1` ?  You make the same mistake in the loop afterwards.

Second, your loops access the array out-of-bounds.  Arrays in C++ are 0-based, but if you look at your loop closely, you go one over the edge:

```
    for (int i = 1; i<=s+1; ++i){
        for (int j = 1; j<=t+1; ++j){
            acktable[i][j]= ack(i-1,j-1);
        }
    }
```

What happens on the last iteration?  You access `acktable[s+1][t+1]`, which is out of bounds.  The highest indices for that array are `s` and `t`, since we start counting at 0.

Comment: I want acktgen (ack table gen) to return the 2d-array, I realized my mistakes in those loops, they're supposed to be less-thans for all of them. And for your last point, seeing as I defined acktable as a (s+1)x(t+1) array, shouldn't acktable[s+1][t+1] be defined? I know we count from zero, but how does that affect how my indices work? Also, code has been edited with some of your suggestions, and more errors came up, specifically involving your std::vector calls.

Comment: If you want to return an array, you can't do it the way you're doing it.  Either return a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` or an `int**` where you create the array dynamically.  And no it is not valid with how you're accessing your array, if you declare this: `int array[10]`, the valid indices are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, and 9.  *Accessing* array[10] is out of bounds.